# How to type the letter Ł

Tags: characters

I am trying to type the word Łojasiewicz. What is the proper command to code the polish character Ł?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The traditional markup (going back to plain TeX) is \L  in current releases you can simply use Ł

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Ł 

\end{document}
```

Prior to the 2018 LaTeX release you would need to explicitly load  `inputenc` as shown below to be able to enter it as is. `fontenc` makes it one character but is not necessary to input it (it'll get displayed by a character "L" and an overlapping dash without `fontenc`). As noted in the comments `\L` is the underlying macro that is used for the character, so you could also use `\L` in every occurrence of Ł.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Ł
\end{document}
```

Without `fontenc`:[image]

With `fontenc`:[image]

If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you don't need the `inputenc` packages as they are unicode enabled by default.

Comment: Funny thing happened I had the package \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} with % in front because I did not know what it was about. It worked thank you.

Comment: You can use `\L` too.

Comment: inputenc always translates to the underlying ascii markup version so you never _need_ inputenc, although it might be more convenient. `\L` is defined even in plain TeX.

Comment: Note that LuaLaTeX and XeTeX work directly with utf-8 encoding. If you compile with either of those and the required `fontspec` package, you can simply paste the character directly from a Unicode character map.

Answer (score 15):

Quick answer:

\L{} or \l{}

Reference: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2239

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hi there, I found lots of answers on the internet, but I know people what something quick and I hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 5):

For example, you can type:

```
Łojasiewicz
\bye
```

and use the command `csplain` or `pdfcsplain` to process the document.